# How can I add the columns different dataframes in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I am currently working with financial data for a fun project and want to add columns to an existing dataframe in the following way: I loop through a list of indicator names and make an API call for each of the different indicators recieving the data as csv. I then want to take the columns without the time column (since it is the same for each indicator) and append them to a dataframe with price data. So far I found out that the following code seems to have the problem since the code before works as it should.

```
inditest = ['SMA', 'EMA', 'WMA']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in inditest: 
    indicator_url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={i}&symbol={SYMBOL}&interval=15min&time_period=60&series_type=close&datatype=csv&apikey={API_KEY}"
    
    # get indicator data from api 
    data = requests.get(indicator_url)
    with open(location + f"{i}_{SYMBOL}_base.csv", 'wb') as fi: 
      fi.write(data.content)

    # make columns for indicator data 
    idf = pd.read_csv(location +  f"{i}_{SYMBOL}_base.csv")
    idata = idf.iloc[:, 1:len(idf.columns)]

    # add indicator columns to existing dataframe
    df = pd.concat([df, idata], axis=1, join="inner")
```

I receive the data from the api just fine so it should be a problem with adding the columns.

To simplify I made an empty Dataframe. In the original df is defined outside of the loop and has 2 columns. SYMBOL variable in my case is AAPL for the apple stock.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame()` is created new in every iteration and shouldn't the merged information be stored outside the loop?

Comment: @HedgeHog yes I need to change that. in the original it is stored outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- Move `time` to the index so `pd.concat` can line up the series correctly. Do not assume that you will receive the same data or in the same order for all series.
- `pd.read_csv` can read from a URL so no need to save it locally.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

base_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"

# All your URL requests share these parameters
base_params = {
    "symbol": "MSFT", # whatever symbol you are after
    "interval": "15min",
    "time_period": 60,
    "series_type": "close",
    "datatype": "csv",
    "apikey": "...",
}

inditest = ["SMA", "EMA", "WMA"]
indicators = [
    # `urlencode` will build the "symbol=AAPL&interval=15min&..." string
    # We only need to prefix it with the `base_url` and add `function`.
    # We also move `time` to the index so `pd.concat` can later align the dataframes.
    pd.read_csv(base_url + urlencode({**base_params, "function": i}), index_col="time")
    for i in inditest
]

result = pd.concat(indicators, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to do the trick, although i don't know how to concat that with the price data.